# ExtJS 5 Label in Toolbar not updated when overflow

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

```
var enableBtn = Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
        text    : 'Edit Label',
        disabled: false,
        scope   : this,
        handler : function() {
            //disable the enable button and enable the disable button
            //enableBtn.disable();
            //disableBtn.enable();

        //enable the toolbar
        //toolbar.enable();
        tFieldPage.setText('7');
    }
});

var tFieldPage = new Ext.form.Label({
            text: 1
        });

var toolbar = Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.Toolbar', {
    //renderTo: document.body,
    //width   : 400,
    enableOverflow: true,
    margin  : '5 0 0 0',
    items   : [enableBtn, tFieldPage]
});


Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
        title: 'Standard',
        closable: false,
        height:250,
        width: 500,
        bodyStyle: 'padding:10px',
        //contentEl: 'content',
        scrollable: true,
        tbar: toolbar
    }).show();
```

I'm using ExtJS 5.0.1 and I found that when you shrink the window and the label '1' goes into overflow menu, when I press the button to update the label, it would not update. However, when I expand the toolbar, the label is updated again. Upon inspection, I realised that when overflow, another label is created automatically. How do I get the original component that I created to update the cloned one in the overflow menu?

I tested the code above using sencha fiddle and the same bug appears as well. Any suggestion or is this a framework issue?

EDIT: My fiddle link : https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1nc7

Thanks.

Comment: Would be better if you share a fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/ to get help on this.

Comment: Hi, I've already added a fiddle link.

Comment: Looks like it is a bug in extjs5. If you try it on extjs6 fiddle, you ll see it is working. What you can do is either start using extjs6 which is very similar to v5, or you can compare `Ext.layout.container.boxOverflow.Menu` class source codes of two versions, and see the missing/buggy part for your problem. Then you can override it easily.

Comment: Hi abeyaz, seems like it still happens in extjs 6. Which version of extjs6 did you test in the fiddle? I chose the latest version (Ext JS 6.2.1.167 Classic). When the menu is overflow and i click the button, the label does not update. It only updates when I expand the toolbar again.

Comment: It looks like it has been partially resolved, but if you resize the view to be narrow and view the overflow while it still says 1, resize it to be wider, click the button, and then narrow it again, it'll still say 1. It seems that behavior persists at least through version 7.1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The label component recreate in private [Ext.layout.container.boxOverflow.Menu](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.0/api/Ext.layout.container.boxOverflow.Menu.html) (two times - I don't research why). For recreate label is using initialConfig of original label. So it's possible:

- to get original label

  - set button handler scope as label
  - get toolbar and then label:`comp.up('toolbar').down('label'))`
- to change original label text: `setText()`
- to set text in recreated label change initialConfig

  ```
  var tFieldPage = new Ext.form.Label({
      text: 1
  });

  var enableBtn = Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
    text    : 'Edit Label',
    disabled: false,
    scope   : tFieldPage,//bind scope
    handler : function(comp, event) {
      console.log('btnhandler scope: ',comp.id);
      console.log('btnhandler scope.owner: ',comp.ownerCt.id);
      if(comp.up('button')){
          console.log('original label: ', comp.up('toolbar').down('label'));
          console.log('recreated label: ', comp.nextSibling());
      }
      this.setText('7');
      this.initialConfig.text = 7;
    }
  });
  ```

Here is [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1o7p)